# redmine error with puma : error transation do error(NoMethodError (undefined method `do' for false:FalseClass))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, redmine, puma

I have a problem with redmine(3.4.11) / puma thread

My redmine is connected two databases (10.3.9-MariaDB, azure sql server)

I have created a model who use dynamics365_database.yml for azure

```
class TIfPmsIssueInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  config_legacy = 
     YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config/dynamics365_database.yml')).symbolize_keys
  establish_connection(config_legacy)
end
```

`dynamics365_database.yml` (MS azure SQL SERVER):

```
adapter: sqlserver
encoding: utf8
database: ky*********
username: pm******
password: rh********
host: ky**********
azure: true
pool: 20
timeout: 25000
login_timeout: 60000
```

I use the following gems:

- tiny_tds (2.1.2)
- activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (4.2.18)

I use Puma threads on redmine

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/wrappers/puma -e production -p 80 -w 12 –daemon
```

But sometimes the following errors occur:

- redmine plugin

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `do' for false:FalseClass):
  plugins/_crm_requirement/lib/_crm_requirement_hook.rb:168:in `crmmap_save'
  plugins/_crm_requirement/lib/_crm_requirement_hook.rb:116:in `controller_issues_edit_after_save'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `each'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `block in call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:in `tap'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:in `call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:91:in `call_hook'
```

_crm_requirement_hook.rb 168 line:

```
TIfPmsIssueInfo.transaction do       
        begin
          crm_issue_info = TIfPmsIssueInfo.where("issue_id = #{issue.id}")
          ...
          ...
        rescue Exception => ex
          error = ex.message
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        end
      end
```

Sometimes it's normal, sometimes an error occurs but I don't know which part of my code is wrong.

Comment: From the error message, it looks like you have some syntax issues there. You likely have written something like `whatever.do` instead of `whatever do` (i.e you have erroneously added a dot before the `do`). Check your code in places at or around locations indicated in the stack trace.

Comment: The error only occurs in the TIfPmsIssueInfo model.
However, it is more often handled normally than if an error occurs.